# How to make .framework file using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I want to build cocoa framework project, but when I build the project I get the `.a` file not `.framework`.

What setting is needed for this?

Answer (score 1):

First, when you are creating the project, be sure that you are selecting the "Cocoa Touch Framework" template.

[image]

After you build the project, the `.framework` file will be created and will show up in the "Projects" folder in the project navigator.

[image]

Comment: in fact, I cloned https://github.com/pili-engineering/pili-librtmp to get .framework with "Enable Bitcode" setting as YES.

Comment: Is this not the cocoa touch framework type project? Can you see the above repository? how can I get the .framework file from there?

Comment: The project you cloned in not a framework project. It is a static library. Converting a static library to a framework would be best asked as a separate question in Stack Overflow, rather than in comments to this question and answer. Maybe try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087900/convert-a-static-library-target-into-a-framework-target-in-an-xcode-project

Comment: In fact, I'm usingLFLiveKit pod, but I got the error like 

LFLiveKit/libpili-librtmp.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Volumes/Work/Task_History/2018_01_05_livestreamApp with MH/live-ios/Pods/LFLiveKit/libpili-librtmp.a
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Volumes/Work/Task_History/2018_01_05_livestreamApp with MH/live-ios/Pods/LFLiveKit/Vendor/pili-librtmp.framework/pili-librtmp(amf.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for archi...

Comment: So, I'm trying to replace pili-librtmp.framework (as bitcode enabled state)