# Adding static framework using Carthage results in "no shared framework schemes"

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I am trying to add a static framework from a private repo using Carthage, but `carthage update` results in 'Dependency "«Repo Name»" has no shared framework schemes'.

Despite the error message, the framework's scheme is shared.

Strangely, changing the Mach-O Type to Dynamic Library fixes this, without making any changes to the scheme. Changing it back to Static Library makes the problem reoccur.

I am using Carthage v0.33.0.

1. Add `github "«private repo name»"` to Cartfile
2. Run `carthage update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue with a static library. The only solution I have found is to convert your static library to a Cocoa Touch Framework (Dynamic).

The reason is because Carthage doesn't add support for Static Libraries.

Here is the source: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2285

This process could maybe help you, good luck!

[Convert a static library target into a framework target in an Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087900/convert-a-static-library-target-into-a-framework-target-in-an-xcode-project)

Comment: Thank you. I needed to keep the static framework for various reasons, so I ended up adding a new dynamic framework target to be used with Carthage.